# date-time local input type manipulation using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

i have a JSP html page with date-time local input field, i am already loading the input field with a value ( coming from backend )

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="scheduleTaskDateTimeBox" style="margin-left: 25px;" name="scheduleTaskDateTimeBox" value="20-08-2018T11:30:45.0" onChange="DateTimeDisplayer()"></td>
```

i want to set the min value to the present date and max value to 90 days (which is already done in the js function), from present date and the user can be able to set a new date-time value(unable to do it!!).

```
    function DateTimeDisplayer(){ 

        $("#scheduleTaskDateTimeBox").attr('required', true);

        scheduleTaskDateTimeBox.style.display = "block";

        var minDateTime = new Date();
        minDateTime.setMinutes(minDateTime.getMinutes() + 30);

        var dd = minDateTime.getDate();
        var mm = minDateTime.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = minDateTime.getFullYear();
        var hh = minDateTime.getHours(); 
        var mi = minDateTime.getMinutes(); 
        var ss = '00.0'; 

        if(dd<10){
          dd='0'+dd;
        } 
        if(mm<10){
          mm='0'+mm;
        }
        if(hh<10){
          hh='0'+hh;
        }
        if(mi <10){
          mi='0'+mi;
        }

        minDateTime = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd+'T'+hh+':'+mi+':'+ss;
        scheduleTaskDateTimeBox.min = minDateTime;

        maxDateTime = new Date(minDateTime); 
        maxDateTime.setDate(maxDateTime.getDate() + 90);

        var _dd_ = maxDateTime.getDate();
        var _mm_ = maxDateTime.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var _yyyy_ = maxDateTime.getFullYear();
        var _hh_ = maxDateTime.getHours(); 
        var _mi_ = maxDateTime.getMinutes(); 
        var _ss_ = '00.0'; 

        if(_dd_<10){
          _dd_='0'+_dd_;
        } 

        if(_mm_<10){
          _mm_='0'+_mm_;
        }

        if(_hh_<10){
          _hh_='0'+_hh_;
        }

        if(_mi_ <10){
          _mi_='0'+_mi_;
        }
        maxDateTime = _yyyy_+'-'+_mm_+'-'+_dd_+'T'+_hh_+':'+_mi_+':'+_ss_;

        scheduleTaskDateTimeBox.max = maxDateTime

        console.log(maxDateTime);   
        console.log(scheduleTaskDateTimeBox);

}
```

somehow this JS function is not working, the value of the new time is not set and returned to the backend.

is there a better way to do it?